# There is no simulator in my xcode 5 after I install xcode 6 beta

Tags: xcode5, xcode6

I have installed xcode 6 beta 4 but after that, when I use xcode 5, there is no simulator can be select, so I also cannot build the project, does anyone encounter this problem? I suppose the xcode 6 is another app so it should not cover the xocde 5, but I don't know why happen for me :(

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have the app set to run on in the active scheme?  Is it an iOS Simulator option?  It should say iPhone Retina, iPad Retina, or something like that (the active scheme settings are next to the Run / Stop buttons).

Comment: yes, I have checked this, but in the scheme, just an iOS device option and there is no any simulators.

Comment: Same issue here I can just see iPadAir for an iPad project but doesn't work and I can't see the other iPad Simulators

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode6 go to **Window** -> **Devices** -> Then you will see sections in the left and a plus button at the bottom. Press it and add the required simulator.