# Missing Simulator in Xcode 8.3.2 after installing Xcode 9.0 Beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-simulator, xcode9-beta

I am using **Xcode 8.3.2** for iOS Application Development.
I have just installed **Xcode 9.0 Beta** and suddenly I found that My old simulators are missing from my **Xcode 8.3.2**.

This issue occurred after installing **Xcode 9.0 Beta**.

See Pictures Below.

**1. Xcode 8.3.2.**

[image]

**2. Xcode 9.0 Beta.**

[image]

I go through links below but none of them is helpful.

1. [Xcode Simulators Missing After Installing Beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160589/xcode-simulators-missing-after-installing-beta)
2. [There is no simulator in my xcode 5 after I install xcode 6 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299665/there-is-no-simulator-in-my-xcode-5-after-i-install-xcode-6-beta)

So please help me for this.

Comment: I have opened a radar for this bug: [All simulators disappear from Xcode 8.3 after having tried Xcode 9 beta 3. It is not possible to re-add them later unless doing a hack.](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6132205541654528).

Comment: For my bug report I got "your report is a duplicate of another issue and will be closed". Hopefully this will be resolved. Still happens to me with Xcode 9 beta 5.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich Just you have to close Xcode-beta. And do this process of opening the Simulator. After that close just Xcode and Restart the Xcode. Sure it will work. It's due to a connection with simulators.

Comment: Generally when I switch between Xcode versions I have change the 1. command line tools 2. delete derived data 3. do what the accepted answer says.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can select Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator and after simulator simulator loads, restart and then you will get whole list back.

[image: Open Simulator Manually]

Note : You can not work on both Xcode with all simulator same time. You have to close one Xcode with it's simulator then you can work on another.

[image: Restart Xcode after loading of simulator]

Restart Xcode after simulator loading process is done. You will get whole list of Simulators.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this didn't work for me. Any other solution.

Comment: @Dh1_Bh1 Just you have to close Xcode-beta. And do this process of opening the Simulator. After that close just Xcode and Restart the Xcode. Sure it will work. It's due to connection with simulators.

Comment: Thanks @AshishKakkad for saving my hair :)

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Note you *must* let the simulator fully boot up before launching Xcode.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, solution is: MacBook restart :)

Comment: I have already tried this many times. so suggest other solution.

Comment: A restart and ensuring that the correct 8.3.x XCode Command Line Tools were selected in XCode Preferences / Locations worked for me

Comment: Same thing happened to me after the most recent XCode update.

Answer (score 9):

**Check your deployment target in the deployment info.**

This might have been changed if you are using latest version of Xcode where your deployment target will be automatically changed to higher versions of OS.

Just switch to older version of OS which will display all the simulators required. 
[image]

Comment: this definitely works. I downloaded a github project that was in Xcode 10.2.1 Swift 5 deployment Target 12.2 and all the simulators were gone. I tried shutting down then restarting Xcode and other answers but this was the only one that worked. I changed the Deployment Target to 11.4 and then the Swift version to 4.2 and all the simulators appeared.

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 10.3 you can get back the simulators by running following command in terminal

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Answer (score 3):

Running multiple versions of Xcode at the same time is only supported if all versions are Xcode 9+.

You can have older versions *installed* but only one running at a time.

If you try running multiple versions of Xcode that don't support it, the currently running one will loose access to simulator services until it is restarted (at which point the other one will loose access to its simulators).

Note that Console.app uses CoreSimulator.framework from the version of Xcode selected by xcode-select.  If you launch Console, and xcode-select points to a different version of Xcode, it will cause the running Xcode to loose access to its sims.

Answer (score 1):

Not launch several xCode in the same time

I was getting this error because i was running two different version of xCode

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to fix this issue.

Step 1: Quit the Xcode 9 and its simulator.

Step 2: Open Xcode 8 and go to Xcode Menu -> Open Developer tool -> Simulator.

Step 3: Quit the Xcode 8 and reopen.

Answer (score 0):

after performing all troubleshooting that people suggest if it does not work for you, then go to preference and tap location tab and verify command line tool version is same as your xcode version , might your xcode command line tool version set to 9 or 9+ , set it back to 8. Hope so this will work for you.after that quit your xcode and open again